# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, activiti

Hi please help I've been using Apache Tomcat as server  and I got errors the detail are stated below. Thank you.

In pom.xml I already have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have the following in persistence.xml file

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activiti" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

I got error like the following

```
2014-10-30 14:24:11,335 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activiti
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
```

Comment: There's no `com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver` in `mysql-connector.jar`

Answer (score 3):

Place you Database Specific JDBC  .jar file in /WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

Change `<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver"/>` to `<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />` to use the right driver class.

Answer (score 0):

go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ 
and press download to download mysql-connector-java 
 then press no thanks

and go to netbeans right click your project - properties - Library - add jar file - and go to downloads and choose the downloaded jar file

For me that fixed the problem .. hope I could help you :)